# Shopify Custom Pixel - How To Return Barcode In Customer Events

Tags: javascript, shopify

I'm trying to return a product's GTIN for the Google Shopping post-purchase survey (https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/7519329?sjid=11531724362774573932-NA), but can't find anyway to return GTIN within the thank you page

In the Custom Pixel / customer events docs (https://shopify.dev/docs/api/pixels/customer-events#productvariant) , there doesn't appear to be any variant.barcode attribute, as there is an the Shopify product API.

Not sure if anyone can recommend strategies to accomplish this, or if this is an appropriate place to ask.

```
lineItems.forEach(item => {
      const variantDetails = item.variant;
      const gtin = variantDetails.barcode;
      products.push({ "gtin": gtin });
      
      console.log(`Added product with GTIN: ${gtin}`);
    });
```

Note: there is no variant.barcode being returned in a custom pixel.